# uncontrolled growth myd file in database

Tags: php, mysql

We have job offer application with mysql data base working on xampp . Everything work fine until today. Queue.myd table files growth out of control and take all available space on hard drive. It's so weird never have that issue before. It works fine for 2 years and now that happend. What could be possible reason of that growth ? Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Are the rows in the table sensible or is it repeating data, or is it just junk?

Comment: In to Queue we loading xml files with job offer from ftp server. This works well for the many customer for a long time. This is the only time we have that issue. I think it could be something wrong with xampp configuration, but it is the same config as the rest. I to change some settings but no reasults yet. If someone have any idea I will be grateful.